# Convexity Adjustments Futures - Sensitivity

Tags: futures, convexity, sofr

If the market prices of SOFR futures are obtained from CME, do we still need to compute convexity adjustments when computing the sensitivity of the IR future?

Comment: The sensitivity to what? Rates? No. An 3M SOFR interest rate future has a sensitivity of 25 USD per bp per contract. This is a static value. Or is it something else you are after?

Comment: @Attack68. i guess sensitivity to the NPV. You're right yes sensi to payoff is like what you described above.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you still need to compute for financing bias, and there will still be some nonlinearity to account for in the 1-month (but not the 3-month) since it uses arithmetic averaging instead of geometric averaging as in the case of the 3-month. But in any case, the adjustment amounts are likely smaller than with LIBOR/Eurodollars.

Long answer: see Chapter 6 of Huggins & Schaller's *SOFR Futures & Options* (Wiley Finance) (you can get 30% off by using [CME's discount code](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/sofr-futures-and-options-guide.html)).